# Tomato plants longevity

Tags: tomatoes, greenhouse

I started tomato plants outside but we had a scorching summer.  I have finally gotten them healthy but it is the end of the growing season.  The question is can I take my plants into my greenhouse and hope for a new crop in the spring? They are about 3 feet tall. I have black cherry tomato and purple prince. Also, will they produce fruit once they are in the greenhouse and I replicate more mild temperatures?  Thanks

Comment: Are the plants in pots or would you have to dig them up?

Comment: They are still in pots of considerable size.  And my greenhouse is considerably warm.

Comment: check out https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-lifespan-of-a-tomato-plant-and-how-can-this-be-increased

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit too late to answer this. But as long as you see a plant looks healthy, you can bring them in. Additionally, you owing to the size of the plant, I think it'd be a cool idea to take the cuttings from that plant and propagate it. Plants grown from any sort of asexual vegetative propagation gives an exact clone of parent plant. People even plant tomato suckers into ground and have had good results growing them.

Thus, you can multiply them by cuttings. Either choose tote method (enclosed containers) or water method to root the cuttings. The newly rooted cuttings will be of same cellular age as of the part of the mother plant where the cuttings have been taken from.

And yes, tomato cuttings perform better in milder climates than when subjected to hot winds.